# Stuck on expressing two linear equations from a word problem despite drawing a chart

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I make a strong and mild version chili dry rub. I mix $200$ g of red chili and $178$ g of sage to make $1$ strong dry rub. I mix $88$ g of red chili and $203$ g of sage to make a mild dry rub. I have $22$ kg of red chili and $13$ kg of sage in a two separate bottles left. Calculate how many kilogram of strong and mild I can make.

I attempted to make a chart: then express in system of linear equation.

1. red chili  Sage Result
2. Mild  $200$ g R $178$ g S 1 mild
3. Strong $88$ g R $203$ g S 1 strong
4. Left. $22$ kg R $13$ kg S = mild or strong

I want to express this in a system of linear equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=$ number of strong dry rub

$y=$ number of mild dry rub

$x(200r+178s)+y(88r+203s) = $ overall amount of substance

So if we expand out then:

$$200rx+88ry\leq22000$$
$$\therefore r(50x+22y)\leq5500$$

and

$$178sx+203sy\leq 13000$$
$$\therefore s(178x+203y)\leq13000$$

I'm really not sure if this is what you want (your question doesn't make much sense) but here are a few inequalities. If the exact $22kg$ and $13kg$ is meant to be used up then you can just replace the $\leq$ with $=$